# Concat strings in a projection (Linq)

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

How can I concat two string in a projection?

This is what I have so far:

```
IEnumerable<NameIdentity> data = null;
JsonResult res;
using (DBContext _db = new DBContext())
{
      data = MyEntity.GetEntities(_db).OrderBy(a=> a.name)
                    .Select(b=> new NameIdentity
                    {
                        ID = b.entityID,
                        Name = String.Join(" - ", new String[]{ b.year, b.name })
                    });
      res = Json(data.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
 }
```

I need to concatenate the year and name properties in the Name propety of my projection.

The error that is giving me is an "NotSupportedException" that says that the LINQ to Entities doesn't recognize de `Join()` method and it cannot be translated to a store expression.

Comment: @It'sNotALie. Sorry, I updated my answer with the real error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 data = MyEntity.GetEntities(_db).OrderBy(a=> a.name)
                .Select(b=> new NameIdentity
                {
                    ID = b.entityID,
                    Name =  b.year +"-" + b.name
                });
```

Comment: This was my first attempt and it wasn't working. Now I tried another time and it worked... I don't know why...

Answer (score 1):

While you are using linq-to-entities you cannot use arbitrary .NET methods in query, You can use [EdmFunctions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.commandtrees.expressionbuilder.edmfunctions.aspx), Here I have use [EdmFunctions.Concat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.commandtrees.expressionbuilder.edmfunctions.concat.aspx)

```
data = MyEntity.GetEntities(_db).OrderBy(a=> a.name)
            .Select(b=> new NameIdentity
            {
                ID = b.entityID,
                Name = EdmFunctions.Concat(b.year, "-", b.name) 
            });
```

You can also use [Canonical](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738534.aspx) functions